# Wordpress 3.4.2 website internal server error 500 but admin panel is working fine

Tags: wordpress, internal-server-error

I have just published my site from **localhost to online server** and there I am experiencing with an **internal server error 500** when I hit my website URL http://www.playinkstudio.com 
but the admin panel http://www.playinkstudio.com/wp-admin is just working fine.

I have read articles over the internet and checked the .htaccess file which is not there in the root directory.
I have changed the theme to default but nothing happened.

Then I had deactivated the plugins but does not worked.

Copied the refresh files but useless.

Any Idea ?

Comment: Do you have a PHP log anywhere? So we can see the cause of the error?

Comment: Sorry,I Don't have an idea for it.

Answer (score 0):

check the htaccess whether it has correct path
if you have just copy that htaccess there need to be correct the path

**Update**

may this could help you 
[link]http://wordpress.org/support/topic/500-internal-server-error-24[/link]
if htaccess is not there create a htaccess file using a text editer having the following code and upload it into wordpress directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: well i have searched through my directory it is not in there

Comment: you seems on windows hosting and using IIS server 
these were the settings for Apache server
anyways you can follow this link
[link]http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942031
[link]http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_on_Microsoft_IIS

Answer (score 0):

Did you updated the site and home url's??

There are two places you need to update your WordPress URL when you plan on changing it.  They are both located under the General > Settings SubPanel.  Update the “WordPress address (URL)” and “Blog address (URL)” values to the new URL for your website.

[image]

Comment: Try re-uploading all files & folders - except the wp-content folder - from a fresh download of WordPress 3.4.2